# Paypal doesn't return the "amount" variable to my PHP script

Tags: php, paypal

This is bizarre. I know my 'amount' variable works because in my form it takes you to paypal and the amount is correct. but for some reason, when I write this file to my server, the 'amount' field is blank.

```
<?php
$data='';
$data=$_POST["item_name"].'|';
$data=$data.$_POST["amount"].'|';
$data=$data.$_POST["business"].'|';
$data=$data.$_POST["custom"];
$imp_file='c:\\demo\\sent.txt';
file_put_contents($imp_file, $data);
?>
```

and here's what $imp_file is outputting

testitem||softworksinc@gmail.com|username|itemid|

The only thing that's different about "amount" from the others is that it will be a floating value, but that shouldn't effect getting it with $_POST should it?

Comment: Is everything else there?  Post what imp_file looks like.

Comment: testitem||softworksinc@gmail.com|username|itemid|

Comment: that's what the $imp_file looks like. It's all there except for amount

Comment: Add it to your question.  People won't find it in the comments.

Answer (score 1):

Try doing a full $_POST dump to the file to see what is actually being received:

```
<?php
  $data = "";

  foreach($_POST as $item => $item_data)
      $data .= $item . "|";

  $imp_file='c:\\demo\\sent.txt';
  file_put_contents($imp_file, $data);
?>
```